# Simple 3D graphics in Scala

Tags: swing, scala, 3d, processing

I am developing a spatial data structure, and I am looking for a quick and easy way to visualize it for the 3D case. I am familiar with Java2D, but not Java3D or OpenGL.

Which library would you recommend for this? I mainly need to draw 3-dimensional points, lines, and cubes. So ideally like the `Graphics2D` API but with an extra z component. No animation, collision detection, textures, < your-favourite-3D-feature-here > needed. It should preferably integrate with Swing/AWT. Parametric view angle would be good, so I rotate around the scene.

Comment: What do you need in terms of functionality? Just a display with perspective and maybe occlusion; or rotation in space, clipping, ...? At least the first few of these are relatively straight-forward to implement, so if this is just a one-off case (you say "quick and easy"), then maybe you're faster doing it yourself than immersing yourself in OpenGL.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Just wires, occlusion would be nice, but it's not 100% necessary. Rotation of view (can be static, I don't need that animated). Java2D backend would be cool, because then I would have a straight forward PDF export facility for figures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Processing:

- [processing.org](http://processing.org)
- [github.com/n8han/spde](https://github.com/n8han/spde)

Answer (score 1):

Dave Briccetti has an excellent set of 3D graphics programs under Scala.  He uses the processing.org framework as a vehicle for easy/flashy/shiny feedback in a series of tutorials on scala.  [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uj_Y3kl9-kI&ab_channel=FunctionalTV][1]

Was able to get many of his code examples to function by dumping them into an eclipse
maven project.   Confess to not having paired down the pom.xml for this workspace+project. It contains the residue of my Big_Data_Scala_Spark day job. If interested in

Scala + Processing_3D_graphics + Eclipse + Maven

please request, and I'll push it up to github after cleaning (and inserting attributions to Dave.)

Answer (score 0):

This looks simple enough, although in Java: http://ozark.hendrix.edu/~burch/cs/490/assn/assn3/